# Loading images in WPF from code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I must have read tons of solutions online, but for some idiotic reason I can not get them to work.

I have a .jpg image in the Resources folder of my project, and the image is set to Build Action: Resource (not embedded resource) and never copy to output folder.
My image is *not* added to my resources.resx file.

I am trying to access the file like so:

```
lResult = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/ImageMissing.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

But this fails saying that there is no image there.

This is so basic I feel really stupid, but I just cannot seem to grasp the simple concept of resources usage.

Thank you.

Comment: Can u plz share a bit more of your code or this might help `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/YourImage.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to specify that the resource being referred to is referenced from the local assembly, then I would think that you would want to include "component". For example, I have some code that loads an icon from a resource available from the same assembly in which my code resides. I write this:

```
var SourceUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyCompany.MyProduct.MyAssembly;component/MyIcon.ico", UriKind.Absolute);
thisIcon = new BitmapImage(SourceUri);
```

As noted in the article available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx, the following additional examples illustrate the use of "component":

The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that is located in the root of the referenced assembly's project folder.

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml
```

The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that is located in a subfolder of the referenced assembly's project folder.

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml
```

The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that is located in the root folder of a referenced, version-specific assembly's project folder.

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;v1.0.0.1;component/ResourceFile.xaml
```

Note that the pack URI syntax for referenced assembly resource files can be used only with the application:/// authority. For example, the following is not supported in WPF.

```
pack://siteoforigin:,,,/SomeAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml
```

Answer (score 2):

You need one more comma in there. Here is the documentation on [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). Notice there are three commas when using the authority.

```
lResult = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/ImageMissing.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: Tried it, but same IO exception.

Comment: @So - Assuming it's in the local assembly and set to Resource for it's build action, that should work. You may try UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, but I doubt that would make a difference.

Comment: @So - Also, if you have .NET Reflector, you can view your resources in that. That will tell you the path in the assembly and whether it's actually there.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use Reflector to achieve this? thanks.

Comment: @So - Open Reflector, select File>Open Assembly File, and open your assembly. Expand the top node and look for the Resources node, and expand that as well. There may be several entries, but double click on each. One will be a list of various resouces, with the first column being the path.

Comment: I found an entry with my resource, the path is "resources/imagemissing.jpg", so the image should be there, but your line of code throws the exception, weird :S

Comment: @So - And the image and the code above are in the same assembly?

Comment: Yes. Weird thing is that from XAML the image loads fine using the pack uri you provided.

Comment: It's the returned value of a converter to be used a Source of an Image control. The converter and control work fine when the converter is converting uris returned by an OpenFileDialog, meaning absolute URIs from the filesystem.

Comment: @So - Did you use the converter when testing the pack uri directly in XAML? Also, is the converter in the same assembly as the jpg?

Comment: No I did not use the converter when testing the pack uri. This image is a special case and is used as a resource, all other images being converted come from the filesystem. And yes, everything is in the same assembly.

Comment: @So - You can try `@"/Resources/ImageMissing.jpg"` or `@"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/ImageMissing.jpg"`

Comment: The first errors "Could not find file 'E:\Resources\ImageMissing.jpg' and the second "Could not find file 'E:\Prototypes\Solution\Project\TestApp\bin\Debug\Resources\ImageMissing.jpg'.

Comment: @So - Last option is `@"pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component/Resources/ImageMissing.jpg"`. Other than that I'm not sure what the issue could be. If you can put together a small project that repros the issue I can take a closer look though.

Comment: I am not positive `"component/"` is not also part of the path. That's number one. Second, make sure you are setting the actual image files as `Resource`. Whereas in other targets, you may have set them to `Embedded Resource`, which does not work, apparently, with _WPF_.

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to rename the file (or folder) in the Solution Explorer and then not clean or rebuild the application?

If you're positive the name in your URI matches what is in the Solution Explorer, then try right clicking the solution and selecting "Rebuild".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the image has not been added to your project - including it in the resources file is not enough.

Right click your project > Add Existing Item > Browse to and find and add the image.

Then all you need to do is:

```
myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ImageMissing.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: The image had been added to the project :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably created this second library as "Class Library" instead "WPF Custom Library". Creating xaml files or embedding images as "Resources" in a class library is not enough for WPF, you are probably missing the following in your AssemblyInfo.cs file:

> Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
  //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
  // or application resource dictionaries)
  ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
  //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
  // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var icon = BitmapFrame.Create(Application.GetResourceStream(
new Uri("MyAppBitmap.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream);
```