# Uri for Images Folder in WPF Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, uri

My project looks like this:

[image]

Ideally I would like to have all my images in the 'Images' folder, however at the moment, I have a bunch of images in Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestProject\TestProject\bin\Debug\Images. I had to do this because as I was trying to find a way to change the source of a ImageBrush in code, I ended up doing this:

```
imagebrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/testimage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

As much as I tried, I just couldn't find a way to point the Uri towards the Images folder in my first picture. Instead, I noticed the above code points towards the Debug folder of my project, hence why I ended up creating another 'Images' folder inside of there. In fact, I even found some tutorials that specifically say to do this when you want to change image sources in code.

This seems wrong however... Especially now that I essentially have two different Image folders. Can someone please explain to me how I can get my code to point towards the Images folder in my picture?

Comment: Are you using images as resources?. You can try pack uri syntax. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Also try the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982625/loading-images-in-wpf-from-code

Comment: Yup the images are just normal resources. Having a look at both your links now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always had trouble with this, but thanks to Ganesh I finally found a solution:

```
"pack://application:,,,/Images/testimage.png"
```

Pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

To access the 'Images' folder from code behind type like this

```
     string imageLocation = @"\Images\myImage.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who will later search for this Guest answer to

```
string imageLocation = @"..\..\Images\myImage.png";
```

Where Images is a folder in the project directory.